# How to use regular expression to find all boundaries adjacent to 'a' and 'b'

Tags: regex

Suppose I have an arbitrary string combined with 'a' and 'b':

```
ab
aba
ababa
aaabbbaaabaaaaaab
```

I'd like to insert '|' between every pair of 'ab' or 'ba', for example:

```
ab -> a|b
aba -> a|b|a
ababa -> a|b|a|b|a
aaabbbaaabaaaaaab -> aaa|bbb|aaa|b|aaaaaa|b
```

Is there possible a regular expression to capture all the group？

Answer (score 1):

You can replace each match of the regular expression

```
(?<=a)(?=b)|(?<=b)(?=a)
```

with `'|'`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nsVj5K/1/)

`(?<=a)` is a *positive lookbehind*, asserting that the match is preceded (immediately) by `'a'`. Similarly, `(?<=b)` asserts that the match is preceded by `'b'`.

`(?=b)` is a *positive lookahead*, asserting that the match is followed (immediately) by `'b'`. Similarly, `(?<=a)` asserts that the match is followed `'a'`.

The matches are empty strings between adjacent letters, often referred to as *zero-width* matches.

One may alternatively use the regular expression

```
(?<=(.))(?!\1)
```

`(?!\1)` being a *negative lookahead*.

Comment: Hey Cary, I found it doesn't work in Safari, is there an alternative expression in Safari?

Comment: I don't know, as I'm not familiar with Safari's regex engine. I wouldn't have answered had Safari been mentioned if the question.